# How to export mail from Squirrel Mail?

Tags: email, export

Is there some magical undocumented way to export mail from Squirrel Mail? I'd like to move some of my friends (who are using my providers mail-hosting services) over to Gmail but I'm clueless as to how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done it before, but it wasn't as magical as you may have hoped for. As Squirrel Mail uses IMAP, there is no tool that I can think of that allows to transfer the emails and the folder structure directly to Gmail. However, you can do it in two steps that way:

Part 1) Set up Outlook Express to use their IMAP server (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264580 for instructions on how to set it up properly). Then sync the folders, which will download all the emails.

Part 2) Use [Google Apps Migration for Microsoft Outlook](http://tools.google.com/dlpage/outlookmigration) to upload the emails in your Gmail account.

Two parts tweak, but at least it works :)